# Domain when dividing two functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Let's say we have two function $f(x) = \sqrt{x-3}$ and $g(x) = \sqrt{16-x^2}$, when finding the domain of $\frac{f}{g}$ do you find the domain of $\frac{\sqrt{3-x}}{\sqrt{16-x^2}}$ so that $x$ is an element of $(-4,3]$ or would you find the domain of $\sqrt{\frac{3-x}{16-x^2}}$ where $x$ is an element of $(-4,3] \cup (4, +\infty)$?

Thanks, any help is appreciated.

Comment: It's $\frac{f}{g}$, so the domain is the intersection of the two domains (minus zeros of $g$, possibly). That you can rewrite the expression is irrelevant.

Comment: I also think so. The domain is $(-4,3]$.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer I don't think it's irrelevant. If you bring everything into the square root, then both polynomials are allowed to be negative.

Comment: @alex The point is that the domain of $\frac{f}{g}$ is asked for, not the domain of a continuation of that.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer Exactly. So $g$ may not be negative.

Comment: In some lectures, there is a difference between "domain", explained by @DanielFischer , and "maximal domain", which would be the biggest possible subset of $\mathbb{R}$ where you can define the function (e.g. by rewriting the expression). You should check which definition you are supposed to use.

Answer (score 2):

It must be $f\geq 0$ and $g > 0$, that is $x-3\geq 0$ and $16-x^2>0$. The solutions are $x\geq 3$ and $-4<x<4$, so the domain is $[3,4)$.